# Configuring networking with network manager

Tags: network-manager

Today, after upgrading Kubuntu from 16.04 to 17.04 network stop working. In the network manager applet there is no connections at all.
So i created one, using ipv4 dhcp and eth0 as an adapter. Situation is simple as hell. How to make this work?

Configuration:
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [man page for NetworkManager](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/NetworkManager.conf.5.html), " If a default NetworkManager.conf is provided by your distribution's packages, you should not modify it, since your changes may get overwritten by package updates."

IIRC, if you manually create/edit this file, you're obligated to create/edit files elsewhere in `/etc`. That's not something I'd recommend if you're running Ubuntu Desktop (with Ubuntu Server, you don't have the option to use NetworkManager, and so must manually configure network connections).

Instead, I'd recommend that you remove and reinstall NetworkManager (`sudo apt-get purge network-manager` will remove any lingering prior-configuration files).

Comment: Playing with `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` i make it work. But I have no idea how i done this